# Perl SOAP Web Service Call With XML

Tags: xml, perl, soapui

I am calling SOAP web services by using Perl with the [`SOAP::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) module as follows:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->on_action( sub { join '/', @_ } )
        ->readable( 1 )
        ->uri( $uri )
        ->proxy( $proxy )
        ->ns( $ns );

$soap->call(
        'method' => ( SOAP::Data->name( ... ) )
);
```

Is there any way of calling customer web service by using XML definition displayed at SOAPUI instead of writing `SOAP::Data` etc? It would be easier if there is an option to do this.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="xxx">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <int:method>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <int:userName>?</int:userName>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <int:password>?</int:password>
      <!--Optional:-->
      ...
    </int:method>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For example, is something below possible?

```perl
    my $xml_string = qq((<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:int="xxx">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <int:method>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <int:userName>$username</int:userName>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <int:password>$password</int:password>
             <!--Optional:-->
           ............
           ...........   
           </int:method>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
));
$xml_string->process;
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I'll write an answer later.

Comment: Do you have a WSDL file or anything else describing the SOAP endpoint? If you've got a WSDL, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11991202/1331451 help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [heredoc](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc) style and submit your whole soap data as normal post request.

You can also then make use of the non-blocking style in case the SOAP response from the remote host takes too long and you have to run other code in meanwhile.

The designers of the SOAP protocol are not happy about this simplified use, because it's too simple.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $username = "MyUsername";
my $password = "MyPassword";

my $hash;
$hash->{variable} = "SomeText";

my $SOAP_request = <<"END_MESSAGE";
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:int="xxx">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <int:method>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <int:userName>$username</int:userName>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <int:password>$password</int:password>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <int:variable>@{[$hash->{variable}]}
           ............
           ...........   
           </int:method>
       </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
END_MESSAGE
```

**Blocking**

```
my $res = $ua->post('http:///www.example.com' => $SOAP_request);
print $res->body;
```

**Non-Blocking**

```
$ua->post('http://www.example.com' => $SOAP_request => sub { 
   my ($c, $tx) = @_; 
   print $tx->res->body;              
});
```

**Reading the response**

```
use SOAP::Lite;
my $som = SOAP::Deserializer->deserialize($tx->res->text);

# Simple xPath navigation through tags
$som->valueof('//Response//SomeInformation//Details');
```